# tensor flow post training quantized model produce nans in cpp

Tags: c++, tensorflow, quantization

I'm suing Tensorflow lite v1.3 to produce a post training quantized model, however after loading the model in cpp it always produces nans. the non quantized version is working though.

what could be the possible reasons for this?